# JS Code increments variable but only re-draws qr code once

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I'm just learning JS and my question might show that...

I downloaded the QR Code generator from this side and played around with it:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/qr_code.htm

It's really easy. There is a formfield

```
<form name="QRform" id="QRform">
    <textarea name="textField" rows="8" cols="70" onkeyup='updateQRCode(this.value)'
      onclick="this.focus();this.select();">Hello World</textarea>
</form>
```

which is calling the updateQRCode function which looks like that:

```
    function updateQRCode(text) {

      var element = document.getElementById("qrcode");

      var bodyElement = document.body;
      if (element.lastChild)
        element.replaceChild(showQRCode(text), element.lastChild);
      else
        element.appendChild(showQRCode(text));

    }
```

Each time the formfield is changed (onkeyup) the QR Code changes.

Now I would like to replace the form with a button (id="increment").

- Each time I push the button, a variable called "counter" increments by one (starting by 0)
- Each time I push the button, the QR Code shall show the new value of "counter"

So I added the following lines to my code:

```
const buttonIncrement = document.getElementById("increment")

        let number = 0
        buttonIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            var element = document.getElementById("qrcode");
            if (element.lastChild)
                element.replaceChild(showQRCode("number"), element.lastChild);
            else
                element.appendChild(showQRCode(number));
        })
```

This works exactly once. After that, the QR Code doesn't change anymore. Spend the evening on debugging, so getting a hint why this doesn't work after the first time pushing my button would be really really appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at the times when you're calling "showQRCode" - in one instance you have the string "number" (ie. enclosed in double-quotes) and in the other instance you have the name of your variable.  That's probably a good place to start

Comment: Absolutely *facepalm*.

But the behavior doesn't change by fixing that... :(